# How to check my mobile network open ports? android mobile device

Tags: android, networking, reporting

I have the [DroidVPN](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aed.droidvpn) app for android and it helps me to check open ports – but not all ports, only a few ports. I need to scan all my mobile listening TCP and UDP (preferable) ports.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variants)</sup>

I want to know if there is an app to do that, or a console (Android console) command for that.

Thanks!

Comment: I have not used any of them, hence I cannot give a real answer – but a pointer I can give definitely: you might wish to see my app listing for [Sniffer, Spoofer & Portscanner](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_sniffspoof) for several potential candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android os monitor
https://code.google.com/p/android-os-monitor/

OSMonitor is a small tool let you monitor your android phone.
Process monitor all processes and display detail information about each.
Network show every physical or logical network interface with statistics.
Connection  display every **tcp or udp** network connection, and query it via WHOIS ( require Google Map )
Misc    monitor processor, battery and file system.
Log check dmesg or logcat in real-time.

kindly note format of open ports is
ex.

x.x.x.x **:46887**

where **:46887** is the open port

Comment: @Cizaquita you're welcome. Glad to see it fits your requirements :)